# (oracle.jbo.NoXMLFileException) JBO-26001: XML File not found for the Container Error

Tags: java, ide, jdeveloper

I'm trying to develop simple swing ADF application with Jdeveloper but I faced this error when I tried to create Master/Detail form. I checked my bc4j file but I think it is fine. Here it is:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<BC4JConfig version="11.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration">
   <AppModuleConfigBag ApplicationName="maintenance.model.AppModule">
      <AppModuleConfig name="AppModuleLocal" ApplicationName="maintenance.model.AppModule" DeployPlatform="LOCAL" JDBCName="Connection1" jbo.project="maintenance.model.AppModel">
         <Database jbo.sql92.JdbcDriverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" jbo.TypeMapEntries="Java" jbo.SQLBuilder="SQL92"/>
         <Security AppModuleJndiName="maintenance.model.AppModule"/>
      </AppModuleConfig>
      <AppModuleConfig name="AppModuleShared" ApplicationName="maintenance.model.AppModule" DeployPlatform="LOCAL" JDBCName="Connection1" jbo.project="maintenance.model.AppModel">
         <AM-Pooling jbo.ampool.maxpoolsize="1" jbo.ampool.isuseexclusive="false"/>
         <Database jbo.sql92.JdbcDriverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" jbo.TypeMapEntries="Java" jbo.SQLBuilder="SQL92"/>
         <Security AppModuleJndiName="maintenance.model.AppModule"/>
      </AppModuleConfig>
   </AppModuleConfigBag>
</BC4JConfig
```

and here is the picture of my Application in the IDE:

[image]

Can anybody Help my I'm new to Jdeveloper and I'm using 11.1.1.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go here

JBO-25058 and JBO-26001 exceptions
http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2008/08/jbo-25058-and-jbo-26001-exceptions.html

JBO-26001: NoXMLFileException 
http://jneelmani.blogspot.com/2009/03/11g-adf-error-list-jbo.html